# Cramer-von Mises using pdf instead of Cdf

Tags: hypothesis-testing, asymptotics

Cramer-von Mises gives a nice way to compare distributions with:

$$
\int [(\hat{F}_n(x) - F_0(x)]^2dF_0(x); 
$$

I'd like to use something like this to compare two empirical distributions, is there a similar statistic that instead uses:

$$
\int_n[\hat{f}_n(x) - f_0(x)]^2df_0(x); 
$$

That is, is there something special about using the CDFs as opposed to the densities?

Comment: On the last, yes indeed. For a start, consider units of measurement here. Cumulative probabilities are unit-free; densities aren't. Also, cumulative probabilities are easy to get from data. Densities (now) are too, except that there are lots of ways to do it and they won't agree in general.

Comment: Because an empirical distribution is *singular,* the second integral is problematic.  The empirical *cumulative* distribution is a far more tractable object to work with than its density!